# 'Set-Variable' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file -- Error when .ps1 script ran in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, scripting, command

PowerShell is giving me the "'Set-Variable' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file" error when I try to use Set-Variable in my PowerShell (.ps1) script. My usage is:

`Set-Variable -Name "CURR_VERSION" -Visibility Public -Value (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\*.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)`

But, in the same window that I'm getting the error in, I tested the Set-Variable command via:
`Set-Variable -Name "age" -Value 23`
and when I then enter `$age` in the terminal session the correct value (`23`) is returned.. So it seems that in the same directory the PowerShell script is run in can use the Set-Variable command successfully, but for some reason it doesn't recognize it during the script's usage of it.

Any ideas as to how and why this could be occurring??

Comment: As an aside: There's rarely a need to use `Set-Variable`; e.g., use `$age = 23` instead of `Set-Variable -Name "age" -Value 23`

Comment: The error message implies that it is `cmd.exe` - not PowerShell - that is trying to interpret `Set-Variable` as a command name, which predictably fails. How are you trying to invoke your `.ps1` script?

Comment: @mklement0 I tried to switch out my use of ```Set-Variable``` for ```$CURR_VERSION = Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\*.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name``` but now it says that ```$CURR_VERSION is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file``` which leaves me even more confused...

Comment: @mklement0 and as far as the implementation of it I package it up as an .exe using a batch script and run the executable from the command line... do you think I would need the batch equivalent for it to work?

Comment: Please update your question to show you're packaging the PowerShell script as an `.exe` file.

Comment: Also show us the **entire** error message. This could also be an encoding problem in the script file